# Recommended root permissions

Tags: permissions

I think I may have gone overboard with `sudo chmod -R`, and I can't open a large variety of programs!

I'm in the root directory at the moment, looking at the following subdirectories:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root       4096 Jun  8 22:00 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root       4096 Jun  8 22:01 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root       4096 Oct 11  2013 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   root       4100 Aug 12 21:41 dev
-rw-r--r--   1 starkers starkers 24853275 Jan 30  2012 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 154 root   root      12288 Aug 12 21:57 etc
drwsr-sr-x   4    666 root       4096 Jun 16 21:13 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         33 Jun  8 22:01 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-23-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         34 Jun  8 22:00 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-23-generic
drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root       4096 Jul 18 11:12 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root       4096 Jul 18 11:12 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root       4096 Jan  9  2014 lib64
drwx------   2 root   root      16384 Oct 11  2013 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root       4096 Oct 30  2013 media
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root       4096 Nov  4  2013 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   root       4096 Jul 18 11:12 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 361 root   root          0 Aug 12 21:40 proc
drwx------   7 root   root       4096 Apr  9 18:01 root
drwxr-xr-x  29 root   root        920 Aug 12 21:41 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root      12288 Jun  8 21:59 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root       4096 Apr 24  2013 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root   root          0 Aug 12 21:41 sys
drwxr-xr-x   9    666 root      12288 Aug 12 21:49 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root   root       4096 Jul 18 11:12 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   root       4096 Jan  9  2014 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         30 Jun  8 22:01 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-23-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         30 Jun  8 22:00 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-23-generic
```

What is the recommended permissions for these folders? 0666 for everything?

I'm hoping to`chmod -R` each back into working order.

Comment: the problem with chmod -R is that it sets the permissions recursively, so everything down the tree line in every of those folders will also have its permissions changed. However, chmod -R alone does not really change anything, you need to give it attributes to modify by, so what was the exact command you executed?

Comment: also why on earth do you have a Download directory in the root of the file system that is not owned by root and that has no execute permissions, not even for the owner? i mean.. what?

Comment: And home & tmp have 666 as the user? I think you mixed chown and chmod commands. Usually any change cannot be recovered as there are many different system owners, not just root and various levels of permissions. Once you reset something in root for either ownership or permissions, it is reinstall and restore from you previous backup.

Comment: and the special bit on the home directory.. if he did -R on any of that it's quite the mess..

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

```
total 108
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  8 19:16 bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Aug 10 08:53 boot
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 17 09:39 BootInfo
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 17 09:26 boot-sav
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 12 18:54 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4600 Aug 12 19:18 dev
drwxr-xr-x 182 root root 12288 Aug 12 08:29 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jul 26 11:33 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Aug 10 08:52 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-33-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Jul 10 19:32 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
drwxr-xr-x  27 root root  4096 Aug  5 19:34 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  5 19:33 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  5 19:34 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 May 12 18:49 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 May 12 20:59 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 19  2012 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Aug  1 10:38 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 418 root root     0 Aug 12 08:26 proc
drwx------  12 root root  4096 Aug 11 21:35 root
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root   920 Aug 12 11:08 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Aug  8 19:15 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 20  2013 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Aug 12 08:26 sys
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root  4096 Aug 12 22:09 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Aug  5 16:32 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 May 30 14:53 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Aug 10 08:52 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Jul 10 19:32 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
```

I haven't, as far as I know, modified them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me guess, you can't access /home, /tmp and /Downloads.

**I.** First of all if you look at the owner of /home and /tmp you will see that they are basically owned by 666, so I`m guessing Satan is also a user on your system. Those two folders however need to be owned by root so chown them to root and then take out the special bit from the home directory, then put the sticky bit on the /tmp and give it full rwx (this one needs to be used by many programs to store temporary data):

```
sudo chown root /home
sudo chown root /tmp
sudo chmod 0755 /home
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Let's hope you didn't change the owner or the rights of those recursively, or you`ll have to work some more to get things back to normal.

**II.** Everything else looks fine except for that mysterious Downloads directory that should not be there. Try to keep your filesystem tidy and not have in the / of it things that are not directly owned by root. Also if you look at that Downloads directory you can't execute it with anything else than UID=0 (root) by the looks of those permissions. 
My guess would be that that is your Downloads folder from */home/starkers* but double check before you do anything so you don't lose data. If that is indeed the Downloads folder mentioned above you need to move it where it belongs and give execute permissions on it as it should have:

```
sudo mv Downloads /home/starkers
sudo chmod +x /home/starkers/Downloads
```

**Again only do this last bit if you are missing the Downloads directory from inside /home/starkers**

**III.** Peace of advice:
Linux really has this way of breaking if you don't know what you are doing when you are running as root. That's why ubuntu forces the sudo command on users, in order to make you think twice about pressing RETURN on the command. If you intend on having linux as your day to day operating system, then I suggest you emulate a second linux box (with say, virtualbox) where you run all the tests you want without the fear of breaking your main OS.